# Best place for Jars

Tags: java, tomcat

A quick question for best practice please if anyone can help.

I am about the implement my project onto a webserver running tomcat. This will host quite a few domains which are mainly static with just HTML code. Mine however includes a database connector and also some JAX jars.

My question is

For best practice is it better to put the .JAR files into $TOMCAT_HOME/lib so that they are avaialable to all webapps, (maybe used by others in the future), or should I keep them in the WEB-INF/lib folder which is webapp specific. If I then build another webapp that uses these JARs I would then have to duplicate them in the WEB-INF/lib folder for that new webapp.

I know it would work either way but what is best practice please.

Answer (score 4):

I would *tend* to keep them per-webapp. That gives you the opportunity to upgrade one webapp without having to touch the others. So you can roll out fixes etc. to one app without having to rebuild/retest the others.

Answer (score 0):

An application server like Tomcat is designed to be able to isolate webapps from one another, enabling them to change independently, use different versions of the same libraries etc. Unless you are *absolutely sure* that your apps will *always* need the same version, and will *always* be ready to upgrade simultaneously (or never) to newer versions, then keeping them per-webapp makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Sound advice. At present I have put them into the TOMCAT/lib . That way my WAR will be smaller anyway. If more webapps are added I will reconsider and move them to each webapp.